# scrollview has no proptype for native prop RCTScrollView.overScrollMode of native type string

Tags: react-native

I am getting bellow issue, is any one have idea about this

> scrollview has no proptype for native prop RCTScrollView.overScrollMode of native type string if you havent changed this prop yourself  this usually means that your  versions of the native code  and javascript code are out of sync

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: same issue here

Comment: I'm having the same problem... any solution?

Comment: Can you please mark one of the answer as solution. In my case Rajan Maharjan's solution works

Answer (score 4):

It's maybe your dependent package version are mismatch, I upgrade my dependencies to the latest, now it works at those versions.

```
"expo": "^21.0.2",
"native-base": "^2.3.2",
"react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
"react-native": "^0.48.4",
"react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.12"
```

Comment: You have no idea how happy you made me! I was struggling with this the whole day (and night before).. Thank you! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

That's a tricky one. Depends on what package manager you have.

You'll have to upgrade react-native.

`react-native upgrade` if using react-scripts

`yarn upgrade react-native` if using the latest create-react-app tools as of August, 2017.

Comment: Victor, wich version of `react-native` is required? I have `react-native` 0.48.3 & `react` 16.0.0-rc.2 and I can't solve this problem in iOS. :(

Comment: This is what I'm using `"react": "16.0.0-alpha.12"` , `"react-native": "^0.47.2"` in my package.json file. Seems to have worked after I run the commands up there.

Comment: In my case, this was the error: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/15875

I just downgraded to `react-native` 0.47.2 and all works fine again

Answer (score 1):

Found the possible [solution](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/16090#issuecomment-332193239)!

```
 1. Bump expo version in package.json to 21.0.2
 2. Bump react-native version in package.json to 0.48.4    
 3. Remove node_modules
 4. npm install or yarn install
 5. Change sdk version in app.json to 21.0.0
```

...
ScrollView is working AGAIN! :)